# A single async event with many subscribers in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java2

I have a class which processes an image which can be a slow process. When the work is done the class contains some features about the image, like the dominant color.

I have many other pieces of code which want to know the dominant color, and when they request it, it may or may not be ready.

I have yet to find a simple way to implement this using RxJava2. Can someone help me?

To sum up, it would be nice if I could create a method which:

1. Allows multiple subscribers to call/subscribe to.
2. When the processing is done, the subscribers receives the result.
3. The subscribers are automatically unsubscripted to avoid memory leaks. There will be no second event, and no reason to still be subscribed.
4. Subscribers which subscribe/call the method at a later point just gets the the cached value.

The ReplaySubject seems to have some of the properties I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> '1. Allows multiple subscribers to call/subscribe to.
>   '4. Subscribers which subscribe/call the method at a later point just gets the the cached value.

Use `replay(1)` in combination with `autoConnect()`. This will result in an observable that shares a single subscription to the source, and replays the last value emitted by the source. `autoConnect()` ensures that the source is directly subscribed to when the first subscriber subscribes.

> 2. When the processing is done, the subscribers receives the result.

Use `Observable.create()` and use the `ObservableEmitter` to emit the result.

> 3. The subscribers are automatically unsubscripted to avoid memory leaks. There will be no second event, and no reason to still be subscribed.

Convert the `Observable` to a `Single`.

---

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
  @Override
  public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    e.onNext("Test");
    e.onComplete();
  }
}).replay(1).autoConnect()
    .firstOrError();
```

Note that you should keep a reference to this `Observable` (the result of `firstOrError()`) and share that instance with the subscribers.